# Elastic Search 5.3 crashes when bulk loading data C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, bulk-load

I have been bulk loading data into a development elastic search server for a awhile. I am using C# to program with and the elastic search server is running on a Windows 2012 R2 Server.  The elastic search server consistently goes down during the bulk load process  I am the only one attaching to the server, so it is not an issue of two people trying to access or insert the same data.  I do not know why this is happening and can't seem to google something that would apply to my situation.  By crashing I mean the service stops(errors out) and restarts.

Here is the code I am using. (I originally had it set too 1000 but reduced because it wouldn't load at all)

```
        var waitHandle = new System.Threading.CountdownEvent(1);
        var response = _client.BulkAll(employees, b => b.Index(indexName)
            .BackOffRetries(3)
            .BackOffTime("30s")
            .RefreshOnCompleted(true)
            .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(4)
            .Size(100)
        );

        response.Subscribe(new BulkAllObserver(
            onNext: (b) => { RaiseMessageEvent("."); },
            onError: (e) => {  throw e;  },
            onCompleted: () => waitHandle.Signal()
        ));
```

Windows Event Viewer (Error):

```
        The Elasticsearch 5.3.0 (elasticsearch-service-x64) service
        terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The
        following corrective action will be taken in 60000 
        milliseconds: Restart the service.
```

Elastic Search Server Log:

```
[2017-07-13T11:06:58,068][ERROR][o.e.t.n.Netty4Utils] 
fatal error on the network layer
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Utils.maybeDie
(Netty4Utils.java:140)....

[2017-07-13T11:06:59,943][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] 
[lm52Lqe] [gc][5070] overhead, spent [1.8s] collecting in the 
last [1.8s]...

[2017-07-13T11:07:00,052][WARN ][o.e.h.n.Netty4HttpServerTransport]
[lm52Lqe] caught exception while handling client http traffic, 
closing connection [id: 0x14bf2d5c, L:/192.168.2.75:9200 - 
R:/10.2.0.70:59266]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space...

[2017-07-13T11:06:58,079][ERROR]
[o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] 
[] fatal error in thread [Thread-62], exiting
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space ...
```

Comment: please share more information from the server side. What does crashing mean? Is hte process vanishing? Is the server still responding but just slow? Do you find anything in the log files on the Elasticsearch side?

Comment: Added requested information

Comment: So I guess no one even has a suggestion?  I am new at using elastic, but I am not impressed with it's performance, documentation, or usage.  If anyone reads, I would not recommend this product.

Comment: the information is still not sufficient. There are no full stack traces for example. My assumption is, that you are trying to load many bulk requests (or big bulk requests) in parallel with not enough heap, but that is hard to tell, is we dont know the size of the whole bulk request.